# What is the equation for how many sheets a newspaper consists of?

Tags: combinatorics

The n th and m th pages of a newspaper $(n < m)$ are printed on the same side of the same sheet.(If we first examine the terms "page" and "sheet," we can observe that 1 sheet = 4 pages. For example, if a newspaper has 8 pages, which is equivalent to 2 sheets, when we take the top sheet, we see that it contains pages 1, 2, 7, and 8. When we look at the remaining sheet, we see that it contains pages 3, 4, 5, and 6.)

What is the equation for how many sheets that newspaper consists of?

This was a multiple choice question so I found the answer as $(m+n–1)/4$ by selecting 4th and 5th sheet and plugging in them into the equations given($(5+4-1/)4$). However, what I wonder is whether this equation can be derived from scratch?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the $n$th and the $m$th pages are on the same side of a sheet, then the $(n-1)$th and the $(m+1)$th pages are also on the same side of a sheet.

Repeat this reasoning, the $[n-(n-1)]$st and the $[m+(n-1)]$th pages are on the same side of a sheet.

This shows that the $[m+(n-1)]$th page is the last page of the newspaper, so the number of sheets would be $\dfrac{m+n-1}{4}$.